# Hide ExtJS Panel Title

Tags: javascript, extjs, title

I have a ExtJS panel inside a viewport center region. I want to hide the title of the panel. How can I do it? I'm using `xtype config` for declaring the panel.

Comment: I wonder why, if you don't want to display a title, you set it in the first place...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use either the `header` or `headerAsText` config option of panel to hide its title. From [ExtJS API documentation](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/):

> header : Boolean
>
> true to create the Panel's header
>   element explicitly, false to skip
>   creating it. If a title is set the
>   header will be created automatically,
>   otherwise it will not. If a title is
>   set but header is explicitly set to
>   false, the header will not be
>   rendered.

and

> headerAsText : Boolean
>
> true to display
>   the panel title in the header, false
>   to hide it (defaults to true).

Comment: With ExtJS 4.x, header:Boolean is now preventHeader:Boolean. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-preventHeader

Comment: For the benefit of Sencha Architect 2 users the 'header' property is the only one available in the standard property list for the Panel widget. It still works in 4.x, however you can just enter preventHeader as a 'custom' property using the property "add" button in Architect. This also works, and will be more future proof.

Comment: `preventHeader` deprecated since version 4.1.0. "Use #header instead."

Answer (score 4):

Use preventHeader property. I checked it and it's worked

See example below

```
Ext.widget('panel', {
        title: 'Panel header will not be shown',
        preventHeader: true,
        width: 300

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the config

```
Ext.panel.Panel({
    // title: 'Test',   to neglet this
    header:false,
    tools: [{
        type: 'refresh'
    }, {
        type: 'help'
    }],
});
```

["header:false config documentation"](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-header)