# how can i hide a title in a Ext.formPanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4

how can i hide in runtime the title of panel??

this is my code:

```
{
  xtype: 'panel',
  id: 'pnlAllCenter',
  border: false,
  layout: {
    align: 'stretch',
    type: 'vbox'
  },
  title: '<center>Main Application</center>'
}
```

now in runtime i need to hide this title! 
(i need something like this Ext.getCmp('pnlAllCenter').title.remove();)

thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExtJS Panel Title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004444/extjs-panel-title)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're quite close...

```
Ext.getCmp('pnlAllCenter').getHeader().hide();
```

**EDIT**

To completely remove the header use

```
Ext.getCmp('pnlAllCenter').getHeader().destroy();
```

Comment: thanks! after this, i see that there is white space of the title, I must also remove it!

Comment: Do you need to show the header again, or is this a one-time removal?

Comment: Can you do this in the configuration? I.e. without having to trigger this call?

Comment: Just don't use the `title` configuration option if you don't want a title. Or did I misunderstand your question?