# How to remove title of grid panel? - ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have one simple grid panel in ExtJs 5

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        height: 700,
        frame: true,
        title: '', 
        ....
});
```

I want to delete the title of grid (or it is title of  panel), but I don't know how. 
i set title:'', title:false, deleted it, but the empty div is still there (before column names)
How to remove title of  grid panel?

PS:

```
 hideHeaders: true //it remove all columns names (header of table)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide ExtJS Panel Title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004444/hide-extjs-panel-title)

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-title):

> #### title : String
>
> The title text to be used to display in the Panel Header. Or a config object for a Panel Title. When a `title` is specified the Ext.panel.Header will automatically be created and displayed unless `header` is set to `false`.

So the solution will be to set `header` to `false` in the configuration:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    height: 700,
    frame: true,
    header: false,
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Setting header to false appears to no longer be an option in ExtJs 6.0.X
Anyone know how to make the title not display in ExtJs 6.0.X?

Comment: @mangotang Try to use     

`titleBar: { hidden: true },` in grid definition. In ExtJS 6.2 Modern works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest versions use config property preventHeader: true/false
true - Title header will not be shown
false - Title header will be rendered